# Magnetic flux density compard to other definition of flux

Tags: magnetic-fields, definition, electromagnetic-induction, luminosity

With regards to flux i have always assumed it was defined as $$(1) Something/m^2s$$
For instance
$Luminosity/(4\pi r^2)$ Is an example of radiation flux.

Why then is faradys law often cited as the rate of change of magnetic flux is equal in magnitude to the induced emf
$$\frac{d\phi}{dt} =\epsilon  $$

where $\phi =BA$
So how can we call $\phi$ to be a flux as dimensionally it is not of the same form as (1).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux doscusses the two different usages of “flux”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on it's a flux of what. Usually flux is defined for a *vector field*. It's obviously so for $\phi(\vec B)$. As to luminosity it too is a vector field: the *current density of energy* - dimensionally energy per unit area and time. But it also has a direction, characterizing it as a vector.